# Quiero hacer una animacion en javascript, pero todo se ejecuta al mismo tiempo

Tags: javascript, css, css3

he estado intentando animar unos elementos con javascript y quiero que las animaciones pasen una por una, pero todo se ejecuta al mismo tiempo.

```
cards.forEach(function(item, index){ //Mover las cartas
    item.classList.add("loaded");
    item.style.transitionDuration = "1300ms"; 
    item.style.transform = "translate("+move+", 50%)";
});
```

el cambio de clases css es este:

```
.fade-in{
   opacity:0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

.loaded{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Pero como se ejecuta todo al mismo tiempo, cuando hace el fade in ya hizo la transicion de  `item.style.transform = "translate("+move+", 50%)";` y entonces no se ve como se mueve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes probar a usar [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) para dar un tiempo de espera entre cada transición:

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

cards.forEach(function(item, index){ //Mover las cartas
    setTimeout(()=> {
      item.classList.add("loaded");
      item.style.transitionDuration = "1300ms"; 
      item.style.transform = 'translate(10px, 50%)';
    },index*300);
});
```

```css
.loaded{
    opacity:1;
}

.card {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

Es importante darse cuenta de que en cada iteración estoy añadiendo 300 milisegundos más que al elemento anterior (por eso es index * 300), porque si simplemente pusiera "300", todas las transiciones se ejecutarían a la vez pasados esos 300 milisegundos